# Finding all GitHub Repo Deploy Keys?

Tags: github, ssh-keys, github-cli

I am trying to add a new SSH key to my GitHub account, but it says the key is already in use. I have hundreds of repos, and I don't want to click through each one to find out which is using this SSH key for deployments. Is there a way to automate this?

Answer (score 1):

My approach to list the **deploy** keys (not the account-level keys) of all my repos:

```sh
for repo in `gh repo list | awk '{print $1}'`;\
  do echo "==== $repo ====";\
  gh repo -R $repo deploy-key list;\
done
```

Comment: Not working like that (anymore?)

Comment: It still works perfectly in my case...  I get a list of all SSH **deploy** keys for each of my repos (I am not speaking of the account's SSH keys)

Comment: Thanks for responding to this cgdave, that made me investigate now. Turns out that the github-cli version that comes with Solus OS doesn't understand `gh repo -R`. Compiled 2.5.2 from sources and all working fine now.

Answer (score -1):

This is now available in `gh-cli` [1.6.0](https://github.com/cli/cli/releases/tag/v1.6.0)+. To list all ssh-keys, execute the below command:

```sh
gh ssh-key list
```

To add a new ssh-key:

```sh
gh ssh-key add [<key-file>] --title "Your Key Name"
```

[Reference](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_ssh-key).

Comment: This command lists the ssh key associated with your account, not the deploy keys configured per project